# how to export aws opensearch Kibana query results to csv (a big file)

Tags: opensearch, kibana-7

I am using AWS opensearch.  I want to export Kibana search results of large size. If the search results have many lines (I know Kibana dashboard Reporting can export small size csv file < 10 MB), and results in big csv file size,  how can export this results?

Thanks,
Arthur

Comment: Do you want to do this regularly? If yes, try to use the API for your request and not Kibana/Dashboard. Kibana/Dashboard is "only" a UI for all possible API calls, so there should be a way to export search results using API, like mentioned here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/export-download-csv-data-from-kibana-visualization-to-api/281599/2